# Emulator AVD manager message

Tags: flutter, emulation

[image]

Hello,

Hello,

Since I installed the new version of android 4.1.3 and I also installed the new version of mac os big sûr 11.3 I have an error when I run the emulator
Could you help me Thanks really for your help

Comment: Android studio has updated the emulator now it's ok

Answer (score 0):

Android studio has updated the emulator now it's ok.

it's not very serious it does not check their updates